# Touch (click) mobile device doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem close my drop down menu in mobile devices only. Is there a way how to remove classes i added before?

There is a Css hover for desktop and clickable for mobile devices.

Thank you for any answers.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.drop_helper').on("click",function() {
   $('.drop_nav').toggleClass('dropped');
   $('.drop_helper').toggleClass('dropped_on').toggleClass('drop_down_btn');
  });
 });
```

```css
li.drop_down_btn {
 color:#a3a3a3;
}

li.drop_down_btn:after {
 color:#a3a3a3;
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f107";
 font-size:16px;
 padding-left: 9px;
}

li.drop_down_btn:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color:#1b2532;
}

li.drop_down_btn:hover:after {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f106";
 color:#1b2532;
}

ul.drop_down {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type:none
}

ul.drop_nav {
    list-style-type:none;
 visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
   position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 26px;
    /* background:url(bg_drop_down.png);*/
    background-color:#FCFCFC;
  
    padding:20px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 khtml-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.drop_nav li a {
    display: block;
}

ul.drop_down:hover ul.drop_nav {
 visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
         -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 2000
}

ul.dropped {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 z-index: 2000;
}

.dropped_on:after {
 color: #1b2532;
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f106";
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-left: 9px;
}

.dropped_on:hover {
 cursor:pointer
}

.drop_down:hover .drop_down_btn {
    color: #1b2532;
}

.drop_down:hover .drop_down_btn:after {
    color: #1b2532;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f106";
}

.drop_down .menu_btn a{
    color: #a3a3a3;
}

.drop_down .menu_btn a:hover {
    color: #1b2532;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="drop_down">
                <li class="drop_helper drop_down_btn">Category</li>
                <ul class="drop_nav">

                    
     <li><a title="Food" href="/posts/food/">Food</a></li>
     
     <li><a title="Fashion" href="/posts/fashion/">Fashion</a></li>
     
     <li><a title="Entertainment" href="/posts/entertainment/">Entertainment</a></li>
     
                </ul>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear but yes with a little bit of jQuery it's easy to remove a class, for example:

```
$('.drop_nav').removeClass('dropped');
```

Will remove the `dropped` class from elements with the `drop_nav` class.

**EDIT**

To also trigger on mobile `touch` events add the `touchstart` event to your `jQuery.on` like so:

```
$('.drop_helper').on('click touchstart'), function() {
...
```

Comment: No, not. It's the same like i have. toggleClass() doing the same, but i have a problem to remove it on touch on mobile device. That's not the same like click. Thank you.

Comment: @zeldax try adding touchstart in addition to click -->  `$('.drop_helper').on('click touchstart'), function...`

Comment: @zeldax Is this in a specific browser or all browsers?

Comment: Is it possible to do it just in Css? If yes, it'll be better solution for me than jquery. :) Thank you.

Comment: It's on all devices with touchscreen. It'll add classes but it doesn't remove.

Comment: @zeldax Hmm ok I'll test it out on mobile when I get a chance later today